# difference between css/javascript selectors

Tags: javascript, css

What is the difference between div#name and #name? Or is there a difference if you use class or id to position a certain element? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use IDs for elements that appear once in the document. You use classes for more than one elements in the page.

> What is the difference between
>   div#name and #name?

div#name

refers to only that div which has id **'name'**

while #name refers to any element having id **'name'**

Answer (score 4):

the first one is more specific if you have several rules applying
for instance, in this example the first case "wins", since it is more specific.

```
div#kuku {color:red}
#kuku {color:blue}
```

A good source for reading: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

Class selectors can apply to many tags, while an id is uniquely associated with a single tag.  So I'd say that a class selector will return multiple elements, while an id selector would return one.

Answer (score 1):

`div#name` limits the selector to DIVs with the id only.

`#name` apples to any element with that id.

As @naivists points out, in case of a concurrency between two rules the more explicit one (div#name) wins.

Comment: `#` filters attribute "id", not "name"

Answer (score 1):

IDs are unique on a page and have more specificity. In other words, if you have

```
<div id="foo" class="bar">
```

Then

```
#foo{
    background: green;
}
div#foo{
    background: red;
}    
.bar{
    background: purple;
}
```

will be red. There is a good **Specificity Wars** explanation of this using **Darth Vader** and **Star Wars** here
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Image here:
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

In brief an **ID** # trumps any number of **classes** (.) which in turn trump any number of tag selectors. e.g:

```
# *beats* . . . .  *beats* body div div ol li p
```

Answer (score 0):

div#name will match

```
<div id="name">foo</div>
```

but not

```
<span id="name">foo</span>
```

#name will match both, but you cannot have both in the same document as IDs are unique in the document, and classes can be multiple.

Answer (score 0):

As for positioning, you generally have a number of elements with a given classname but id is specific to a single element. You generally do not want to position a number of elements at the same time, unless it is for only 1 axis.